# AngularJS: Wrapping Directives and passing the attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive

I am looking for a way to extend or wrap a third-party directives html with Angular 1.5.

---

Given a directive

```
<lib-input></lib-input>
```

I want to create a directive `<my-lib-input>` which renders the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <my-directive></my-directive>
    <lib-input ng-if="vodoo()"></lib-input>
</div>
```

Which is supposed to be used in the same way as the original directive.

---

**Example**

To use my directive in the same way as the original, i need to move all attributes to a specific node of my template:

```
<my-lib-input ng-model="model" ng-change="ctrl.onChange()"></my-lib-input>
```

should generate:

```
<div>
    <my-directive></my-directive>
    <lib-input ng-if="vodoo()" ng-model="model" ng-change="ctrl.onChange()"></lib-input>
</div>
```

However angular applies all the attributes to the root-node (here: the `div`) by default.

**Question**

How do I apply all parameters/ attributes which are passed to my directive to a specific node of the template?

---

I would like to prevent hardcoding a list of available parameters in my directive like:

```
restrict: 'E',
scope : {
    ngModel: '=',
    ngChange: '&',
    ...    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have chaining of scope parameters like 
Working JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/833pgujc/)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.input = 'LibInput';
  $scope.changeInput2 = function(i2) {
    $scope.myInputs.setInput2(i2);
  }

  //this is releaving module which have getters and setter and variables can be hidden from outside scope.
  var getInputData = function() {
    var input1 = 'Input1';
    var input2 = 'Input2';
    return {
        getInput1 : function() {
        return input1;
      },
      getInput2 : function() {
        return input2;
      },
      setInput1 : function(i1) {
        input1 = i1;
      },
      setInput2 : function(i2) {
        input2 = i2;
      }
    }
  }

  $scope.myInputs = getInputData();
});
myApp.directive('libInput', function() {
    return {
    restrict : 'E',
    scope : {
        input : '='
    },
    template : '<div>{{input}}</div>'
  }

});

myApp.directive('myLibInput', function() {
    return {
    restrict : 'E',
    scope : {
        input : '=',
      myDirInput : '='
    },
    template : '<my-dir other-input="myDirInput"></my-dir>\
                            <lib-input input="input"><lib-input>'
  }

});

myApp.directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
    restrict : 'E',
    scope : {
        otherInput : '='
    },
    template : '<div>{{otherInput.getInput1()}}</div>\
                            <div>{{otherInput.getInput2()}}</div>'
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly what i would like to avoid since i would need to specify every single scope parameter which might be passed to an input-directive. Not just because it is a "long" list, but because my directive would not be compatible with anything that i did not anticipate (for example functionalities that might be added in future updates).

Comment: You can require your parent directive's controller to get the list of parameters. If you want, i can update the answer.

Comment: That sounds great, i would really appreciate an example!